# getting value of undefined when using @ViewChild to get <gridster-item> element?

Tags: javascript, angular

my issue it is:

Angular 11.0.0
angular-gridster2 11.1.5

Cannot access gridster-item element with ViewChild decorator

getting value of undefined when using @ViewChild to get  element?
html

```
<mat-dialog-content #dialogContent2  style="height: 38vw !important; max-height: 38vw !important;">

  <mat-tab-group id="tabGroup" #tabGroup2 (selectedTabChange)="changedOptions(tabGroup)" animationDuration="0ms" mat-align-tabs="center">
    <mat-tab #tap2 *ngFor="let dashboard of dashboards.tabs; index as tapIndex" [label]="dashboard.name">

      <div #div2 dir="ltr" class="certificateBox" [style.width.mm]="dashboards.view.width" [style.height.mm]="dashboards.view.height" >   
        <gridster #gridster2 [options]="options">
          <gridster-item #gridsterItem2 id="gridsterItem" style="background: none;" [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard.details.contents; index as i">
          </gridster-item>
        </gridster>
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

typescript

```
@ViewChild('dialogContent2')  dialogContent2;
@ViewChild('tabGroup2')  tabGroup2;
@ViewChild('tap2')  tap2;
@ViewChild('div2')  div2;
@ViewChild('gridster2')  gridster2;
@ViewChild('gridsterItem2')  gridsterItem2;

ngAfterViewInit(){

  console.log(this.dialogContent2)) /* works finke */
  console.log(this.tabGroup2)) /* works finke */
  console.log(this.tap2)) /* works finke */
  console.log(this.div2)) /* works finke */
  console.log(this.gridster2) /* works finke */
  console.log(this.gridsterItem2) /* undefined */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The component in question is part of an `ngFor` you should use this instead:

```js
@ViewChildren('gridsterItem2') gridsterItem2: QueryList<GridsterItem>
```

And in your code, remember that it is an iterable (collection).